# Media Queries in React: How to pass a variable to size=full prop in <Drawer> component

Tags: reactjs, media-queries, create-react-app, drawer

```
const isMobile = useMediaQuery('(max-width:992px)');
```

Old Syntax:

```
<Drawer full={isMobile}></Drawer>
```

But acc to new changes, here: [Rsuite](https://rsuitejs.com/components/drawer/)

> full is Deprecated. Use size="full" instead for Full screen

So, New Syntax would be:

```
 <Drawer size='full' ></Drawer>
```

In this case, how to pass the `isMobile` to Drawer component?

Comment: Hmm your `Rsuite` link is just a link to stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Blundering Philosopher I should've double checked. Thanks for pointing it out, I'll keep it in mind from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can done with it like this

```js
<Drawer size={ isMobile  ? 'full' : 'sm'} ></Drawer>
```